# how to get my clawhand to grab my objectholder?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image][![ hey guys so i need help please! i need my claw hand to be able to grab my object holder(orange thingy next to the red ball. my objectholder has a spring joint already so I want my clawhand to be able to grab it and pull it with the ball. When my hand opens then it shoots. But when I try to grab it, my hand goes right through.
My claw hand has rigidbody,box collider,configuration joint and is animation by this code

```
public class open2close : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Animation anim;
    Rigidbody rb;
   

    void Start()
    {
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        
    }


    void Update()
    {
        //********************Open pincher ********************
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X))
        {
            anim.Play("clawopen");
        
            
        }
        //*******************Close pincher ********************
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Y))
        {
            anim.Play("clawclose");
           
        }


    }
}
```

as for my object holder it has box collider,spring joint, rigidbody, and rotation constraint. Can someone guide me or help me in what i can do thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to not have a collider on the claw hand. This is because you are mixing rigidbodies with animation, which can get messy. I would reccomend keeping everything, excpt for the box collider on the claw hand. **Set it to a trigger**. You can put booleans in the if statements to open and close the claw. This way, you can set the position of the objectholder to be at the claw (if they are touching).

Change your script to something like

```
public class open2close : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Animation anim;
    [SerializeField] bool isClosed;
    Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X))
        {
            anim.Play("clawopen");
            isClosed = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Y))
        {
            anim.Play("clawclose");
            isClosed = true;
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider obj)
    {
        Rigidbody colRb = obj.attachedRigidbody;
        if (colRb != null && isClosed)
        {
            colRb.position = transform.position;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works and be specific! thanks :)

Comment: ok so im tryng it right now but its giving me an error on GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo

Comment: also if i get rid of the box collider how can I trigger it?

Comment: @alexa You can remove the GetCurrentStateInfo, and just set isClosed to true inside the if y is pressed.

Comment: @alexa I mean set isTrigger to true in the box collider component

Comment: So ... it made my whole arm go crazy. It was all over the place when I did everything.

Comment: Try removing all colliders from your arm and disable the OnTriggerEnter method and makeIsClosed a public variable, so you can check if the value is true when it should be. + I edited the script

Comment: The problem may be with the spring joints. Try disabling them for a moment

Comment: Oh, try changing it to obj.attachedRigidbody

Comment: ok wait.. im getting confused lol. So i got the code working. Do you want to me to uncheck the box colliders of all my joint of my arm ?

Comment: You should not need any box colliders on your arm. They may not be the problem, but it's worth a try

Comment: ok so no triggering as well? My arm is made of capsole colliders and even if i get rid of them the arm stops moving completely, i cant control it with no keys

Comment: Keep the colliders on, then. Set the collider on the claw to a trigger collider

Comment: If you want, go to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248144/unity3d. I haven't tested it, but it is a chat room I created, so you can talk easier.

Comment: ok i will join.

Comment: @alexa Are you getting the messages, because I was sending them?

Comment: I am but its not letting me send messages

Comment: Should work now. You have 21 rep

Comment: i reenetered but it says i still need the 20 reps. Maybe make a new chat?

Comment: Ok. You might have to wait about 24 hours to chat. Can you wait that long to solve this issue?

Comment: yea I have no problem with waiting. Ill try some things in the mean time. For the objectholder should i add the code you meantion in the other post before? i added it before but should i leave it?

Comment: No. You don't need it. Just this script on the claw, and no script on the objectholder

Comment: ook i texted you on another chat , on my last post . I dont know if you got it